# Unit test timeout in Rust

Tags: unit-testing, rust, timeout

Is there a way to specify a timeout for a specific unit test in Rust?

The only way to do it so add it to the test case as a hardcoded argument: https://docs.rs/ntest/0.7.2/ntest/index.html

But I wanted to ask if there is a way to provide in the command line as an argument to running test. Something like:
`cargo test <timeout?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get help on the test runner with `cargo test -- --help`. In particular you will find:

```
--ensure-time   Treat excess of the test execution time limit as
                error.
                Threshold values for this option can be configured via
                `RUST_TEST_TIME_UNIT`, `RUST_TEST_TIME_INTEGRATION`
                and
                `RUST_TEST_TIME_DOCTEST` environment variables.
                Expected format of environment variable is
                `VARIABLE=WARN_TIME,CRITICAL_TIME`.
                `CRITICAL_TIME` here means the limit that should not
                be exceeded by test.
```

Comment: I think this is not an actual timeout, just failing if exceeded. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Chayim is correct, `--ensure-time` only considers a test failed if it runs for too long, it does not actually terminate long-running tests.  Also, bear in mind that as of July 2023, it is a nightly-only option, and requires `-Zunstable-options` to be passed to the test executable.